# Использование gpu на Android

Tags: android, распараллеливание, cuda, gpu

Возможно ли на Android каким-либо образом напрямую задействовать GPU для каких-либо задач? И целесообразно ли это, то есть получится ли какой-то выигрыш в производительности при распараллеливании? Как на Cuda от NVidia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно, но только для строго ограниченного набора устройств.

В частности, тот же Cuda доступен для Android'а - [ссылка](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#technologies/mobile/cuda_android_main.htm)

Утверждается, что пока на рынке есть только 1 графический процессор для Android устройств с поддержкой CUDA - NVidia Tegra K1 - используется в основном только для Android планшетов NVidia

Кроме известной CUDA, имеется еще стандарт [OpenCL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), который имеет более широкую поддержку в Android устройствах. В частности OpenCL поддерживается для GPU Adreno и Mali (устройств с этими процессорами достаточно много на рынке).

Примеры программирования на OpenCL для Android - [здесь](https://arrayfire.com/getting-started-with-opencl-on-android/)

Надеюсь, понятно, что для применения всех этих красот - будет нужен [Android Native Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)